# is my understanding of this pseudo-code correct? if so, how do I calculate big theta of it?

Tags: pseudocode

This is the pseudo-code.

[image]

This is how I understand it:

Line 2 will execute n/5 times

Line 4 log(n) times

Line 5 is j times

So this means that line 6 will execute n/5 * log(n) * j times, is this right?

If so, how do I continue from here to calculate big theta? How does j play into things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 2 - not quite, i is multiplied by 5 each loop, so the loop will execute 5-to-this-power-is-n times which is log_5(n). `i` is not used below, so this just multiplies the complexity by log(n).

We can ignore the base of the log, that's just a multiplicative constant.

Line 4 - loops log n times

Line 5 - and the inner loop squares the previous loop (because sum 1..X = X*(X+1)/2, approximated as X^2)

So ... log^3(n) overall?